# Spring Security Facebook Authentication doesn't work

Tags: grails, spring-security

I just installed this plugin  from [here](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-facebook).

After installing and configured  the whole app went down working.

When I hit any link of my app, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'accessToken' on null object
    com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.DefaultFacebookAuthDao.create(DefaultFacebookAuthDao.groovy:110)
    com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthProvider.authenticate(FacebookAuthProvider.groovy:39)
    com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthCookieTransparentFilter.doFilter(FacebookAuthCookieTransparentFilter.groovy:47)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Why this exception occurs?

#### Edit:

The exception I'm getting is:

```
2012-11-16 18:58:28,662 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR facebook.FacebookAuthUtils  - Can't read data from Facebook
Message: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    Line | Method
->>   96 | requestAccessToken in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthUtils
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     90 | getAccessToken     in     ''
|     35 | authenticate . . . in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthProvider
|     47 | doFilter           in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthCookieTransparentFilter
|   1110 | runWorker . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run                in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread

[http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR facebook.FacebookAuthProvider  - Creating user w/o access_token
[http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR [/presto].[gsp]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [gsp] in context with path [/presto] threw exception
Message: Cannot get property 'accessToken' on null object
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you turn on logging for `com.the6hours` and show log output before exception?

Comment: Ok, I see. Are you using any `redirect_uri` value for initial authentication?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov: Nope I don't.

Comment: please let me know if this is fixed. I am facing this issue

Comment: same problem here, still no fix ?